# <User: root> is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-2.7

i am trying to display a chart that shows the number of books that are  related to each user , and i am getting the right result in the shell, but when i render my template, i get the following error :  is not JSON serializable

## my template_tag

```
@register.simple_tag()
def chart_data():
    users = User.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('books'))
    return json.dumps({
        'labels':[user for user in users],
        'series':[[user.num_books for user in users]]
    })
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be from this? As the error says, you can't pass model instances directly to json.dumps.

Comment: i want the final output to be a chart that display the number of books for each user, for example the user " root" has 50 books and so on . and i am using chartist.js

Comment: Well that wasn't what I asked at all. You're trying to output JSON from this template tag; what do you want that to look like?

Comment: now i got it working , thanks Mr  Roseman i just followed the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing this because you're trying to encode a Python `class` object to JSON, but the json module doesn't support serializing a Python `class`.

Only objects that json supports are [listed here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

To fix this, instead of serializing the `User` object, try serializing that user's username. Change the 5th line like this:

```
'labels':[user.username for user in users],
```